# Can I toivel in a mikveh two hundred times in one minute?

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath

When men are toivel in a mikveh for either tosefes kedusha or for tevilas Ezra there is an accepted idea by some that the more often you are toivel in succession the better it is or the more kedusha a person acquires. Many people, have come up with the kuntz of staying under the water but splashing their hand or finger in and out of the water in quick succession, in that way halachically being fully under the water and coming out over and over again in quick succession, without having to actually have to bring the head in and out of the water.

Does that kuntz work? 
Is it considered separate tevillas or does the head have to come out of the water and go back in, to be considered separate tevillahs? 
I would appreciate sources besides people's svarahs.

Comment: related (reasons for multiple dipping) http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/79423/759

Comment: @MarkA You have some of the best q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶t̶i̶t̶l̶e̶s̶ questions on Mi.Yodeya, if not on Stackexchange.

Answer (score 4):

<sup>See my answer [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/79434/501) regarding the problems with dipping more than once. But to address your question:</sup>

The Gemara in [Chagiga 19a](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01139.html#HtmpReportNum0034_L2) discusses what would happen if you had a Mikveh with precisely the minimum 40 Se'ah. Once one person dips, then next person is left with a non-Kosher Mikveh, as the water that is on the first person is now missing. There's an argument as to what happens if the first person still has his feet in the Mikveh.

Rabbi Yehuda is of the opinion that as long as all the water is still connected to the Mikveh - for example, the first person's feet are still in the water - then the second person can dip and it's a Kosher Mikveh.

The Gemarah goes so far as to ask that according to Rabbi Yehuda can one toivel needles in the first person's wet hair, if he's still standing in the water.

The Shulchan Aruch paskens in [סימן רא - דיני המקוה ומימיו](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_30.html#HtmpReportNum0000_L2) that once the first person emerges from the water, the Mikveh is already missing some water.

> **סב:** מִקְוֶה שֶׁיֵּשׁ בּוֹ מ' סְאָה מְצֻמְצָמוֹת, הָאָדָם הַטּוֹבֵל בְּתוֹכוֹ לֹא יִקְפֹּץ לְתוֹכוֹ, שֶׁלֹּא יַחְסְרוּ הַמַּיִם בִּקְפִיצָתוֹ בְּתוֹכוֹ; וְלֹא יִטְבֹּל בּוֹ  פַּעֲמַיִם זֶה אַחַר זֶה; **טָבְלוּ בּוֹ שְׁנַיִם זֶה אַחַר זֶה, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁרַגְלָיו שֶׁל רִאשׁוֹן נוֹגְעוֹת בַּמַּיִם, הַשֵּׁנִי בְּטֻמְאָתוֹ**, שֶׁהֲרֵי חָסְרוּ הַמַּיִם מֵאַרְבָּעִים סְאָה.‏

Point being, that whichever limbs are no longer submerged are considered to be disconnected from the Mikveh - and immersing them would once again be a Tevila.

So every time you splash your hand out of the water, even if it's still wet, it would be as if you exited and reentered the Mikveh.

However, if all you're doing is creating a wave, so that your hand didn't emerge from the water even though it's above the water line, then you are still immersed.

So once you start splashing really fast you are probably not Toiveling multiple times anymore.